# How to capture child's event.target?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to get the value of e.target inside the visual parent of a movieclip( ChildClass). Please see the ********************** in the following code.

```
public class ParentClass extends MovieClip 
{

  public function ParentClass()
  {
     addEventListener( ChildClass.SOMETHING_HAPPENED, somethingHappened)
  }

  public function somethingHappened(e:Event)
  {
      //**************************************************
      //**************************************************
      // WANT TO GET THE VALUE OF e.target (ie. instance of SimpleButton) OF CHILD CLASS 
      //****************************************************
      //**************************************************
   }


}


   public class ChildClass extends MovieClip
{
         public static const SOMETHING_HAPPENED:String = "someThingHappened" ;

  public function ChildClass()
  {
     my_btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, my_btn_CLICK)
  }

  public function my_btn_CLICK(e:Event)
  {
        dispatchEvent( new Event(ChildClass.SOMETHING_HAPPENED));
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that an event dispatched from an object on the display list will pass through every container above it. Say your display list looks like

```
stage
> parent
> > child
> > > button
```

If `button` dispatches an event, then you can listen for it on `stage`, `parent`, `child`, and `button`! Because of this, you can have `button` dispatch the event but listen for it up on the parent.

In your child class:

```
private function my_btn_CLICK(e:Event):void
{
    button.dispatchEvent(new Event(SOMETHING_HAPPENED));
}
```

Now, in your parent class:

```
public function somethingHappened(event:Event):void
{
    trace(event.target);        // The target will be the button.
    trace(event.currentTarget); // The current target will be this object.
}
```